# Setting Google Map Markers and Assigning Bounds - Android

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, google-geocoder

Here's the situation. I'm trying to create markers that only show up when they are 1 longitude and latitude away. I'm also trying to get the LatLngBounds to fit the markers within 1 latlng markers on the map from the outset.

I can get everything to work but not at the same time. I must doing something wrong with my If/Else statements.

```
protected void onPostExecute(Address address) {
        mMap.clear();
        if (address == null) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.invalid_entry, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            String addressName = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                addressName += " - " + address.getAddressLine(i);
            }

            Double longitude =  address.getLongitude();
            Double latitude =  address.getLatitude();

            LatLng position = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());

            LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
            builder.include(position);
            builder.include(position);

            //search location
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(position).title(addressName)
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE)));

            for (int i = 0; i < markers.size(); i++) {
                Double distanceLng = Math.abs(markers.get(i).longitude - longitude);
                Double distanceLat = Math.abs(markers.get(i).latitude - latitude);
                if ((distanceLng < 1) && (distanceLat < 1)) {
                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(markers.get(i))
                            .title("Place")
                            .snippet("Description"));
                    builder.include(markers.get(i));
                    LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
                    int padding = 50; // offset from edges of the map in pixels
                    CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, padding);
                    Log.d(TAG, "DistanceBounds: " + bounds);
                    Log.d(TAG, "DistancePadding: " + padding);
                    Log.d(TAG, "DistanceI: " + i);
                    mMap.moveCamera(cu);
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.no_places_in_area,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(position, 10));
                    Log.d(TAG, "DistanceLng Failed = " + distanceLng + "i = " + i);
                    Log.d(TAG, "DistanceLat Failed = " + distanceLat + "i = " + i);
                }
            }


        }
```

Any help with the writing the right code would be appreciated!

Comment: Whare are you adding `builder.include(position);` two times, probably a typo

Comment: Also as you said `1 longitude and latitude away` then you should subtract   `distanceLng` from `distanceLat`

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the Math.abs() method which returns the absolute value of given number i.e Math.abs(-10) will return your 10. I would suggest you to use Math.floor or Math.ceil as per your requirement.

```
System.out.println(Math.ceil(25.46)); // Prints 26
System.out.println(Math.floor(25.46)); // Prints 25
```

this will give you the exact subtracted value. As the value of latitude and longitude are always in double so it might be possible the your will not get the exact value of 1 as per your requirement.